# android studio: "The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size"

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-signing

I'm getting following error when I build my android studio project.

```
The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
```

Several forums say that I've to create a new SHA key for my project but I believe that it will hinder me to upload updates for my google playstore app.

Please suggest me what is the suitable way to resolve this error.

Information from app gradle is as follows.

```
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 31
```

Comment: Is this an app already on the Play Store?  And do you use Google Play Signing?  If the first question is no, just make a new key.  If the second question is yes, make a new key.

Comment: It's an app already there on the Play Store. I can try using Google Play Signing. To make a key to resolve this error, what is the command to be used?

Comment: I've used following command to generate the key. But this is not solving this issue. 
`keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Comment: Google Play Signing is IMHO the way to go. If I understand it correctly it will allow to update the signing key (generate a new one) for devices running API 24+ while older devices will still get the app signed with the old key. That way you would be able to step-by-step migrate to a new signing key.

Comment: Can anybody help with this on how to create a new signing key?